# vim: change pwd while working with cscope

Tags: vim, ctags, neovim, cscope

I'm currently working on project using vim+cscope.

Sometimes, to make some code-exploring tasks easier I use **:cd** command to navigate to a specific folder withing the project. But then, if i want to issue some cscope command such as **Ctrl-]** or **:cscope find** it won't work before i change back to my project's root directory. I understand that's because cscope just tries to open the path as it is written in the cscope_db file without any sophistication.

So how do i make cscope "remember" my project's root directory so wherever i am it will always know to open the right path?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently **:set csre** did that for me:

> basename of cscope.out location (usually the project root directory) will be used as the prefix to construct an absolute path.

Due to some misconfiguration I missed it.